# shift all the zero values to the end of the array

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

How to write a code in python to shift all the zero values to the end of the array (There is a constant size integer array containing list of positive values (greater than 0). There are
also some zero values in between data).

Example array [ 5 ,10, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 3 ]

I tried this way but its repeating the 3

```
    x=[5,10,0,4,0,8,0,3]
for i in range(1,8):
    if x[i]==0:
        for j in range(i,8):
            x[j]=x[j+1]

for i in range(0,8):
    print(x[i] )
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do with this solution but there are a couple of problems: The index 8 is out of bounds. It is hardcoded and works only for this specific array. When you move all the element to the front, you don't set the remaining part at the end to zeros. This results in the tail of the result being all 3s. And last but not least, the time complexity of this solution, when done right, is quadratic while you can do this in linear time.

Comment: I have added a corrected version of your proposed solution to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simplified version of the [Dutch National Flag Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) where you try to partition an array into 3 distinct parts instead of the 2 here.

The way you can solve this is by the two-pointer technique. One pointer `A` indicates that all element behind it are definitely non zeros while another pointer `B` moves forward looking for non-zeroes. Whenever `B` finds a none-zero it swaps that element with the element at index `A` and `A` is incremented. This results of all the non-zero elements landing to the left of `A` and all the zeroes to the right of `A` at the end.

```py
def partition_zero_nonzero(arr): 
    l = 0   
    for i, el in enumerate(arr): 
        if el != 0: 
            arr[l], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[l]  
            l += 1  
    return arr
```

A quick test:

```
arr =  [ 5 ,10, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 3 ]
partition_zero_nonzero(arr)
[5, 10, 4, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Please note that this method also respect the relative ordering of the original array.

Of course, it is also possible to solve this problem by using additional space, adding all the non-zero element to the new array and filling the rest with zeros.

**Update:** Since you posted a solution with quadratic time complexity and asked if it's correct. Here is your corrected solution. I reiterate that it is really not efficient and you can do a lot better but it's fine for educational purposes.

```py
def partition_zero_nonzero_quadratic(arr): 
    n_zeros = 0 
    for i in range(len(arr)): 
        if arr[i] == 0: 
            for j in range(i, len(arr)-1): 
                arr[j] = arr[j+1] 
            n_zeros += 1 
    for i in range(len(arr)-n_zeros, len(arr)): 
        arr[i] = 0 
    return arr
```

Small test:

```
arr = [ 5 ,10, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 3 ]
partition_zero_nonzero_quadratic(arr)
[5, 10, 4, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I have updated it with a answer. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why not `remove` and `append` upon `0` encounter? This should equal a shift operation from a semantic point of view.

```py
ex = [ 5 ,10, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 3 ]

for e in ex:
  try:
    ex.remove(0)
    ex.append(0)
  except ValueError:
    break

print(ex)  # [5, 10, 4, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I have updated it with a answer. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would achieve what you need:

```
v = [5, 10, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 3]

v1 = [x for x in v if x != 0] + v.count(0) * [0]
```

or, more generally - this allows you to specify any number *target* at the end:

```
def target_at_the_end(v, target = 0):
    return [x for x in v if x != target] + v.count(target) * [target]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to loop over the list and separate the `zero` and `non-zero` elements of the list and append them to separate lists respectively. Then after that combine both the lists.

```
x=[5,10,0,4,0,8,0,3]

def list_partition(non_zero_list, zero_list):
    
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]==0:
            zero_list.append(x[i])
            
        elif x[i]!=0:
            non_zero_list.append(x[i])
            
    list3=non_zero_list+zero_list
    return list3

final=list_partition([], [])
print(final)
```

This gives the output as follows:

```
[5, 10, 4, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```